# ambiguous implicit values when using contravariant generic type

Tags: scala, implicit, scala-macros

I've run into a problem with inferImplicitValue in a scala macro. I was playing around with a macro for play's json libary `Format[T]`.
I could narrow it down to a problem how `Writes[T]` is sometimes implemented with `OWrites[T]`. Together with an explicit type declaration on
an `implicit val`, this led to the following compiler error.

```
[error] ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value xm in object TestTest of type => OMaterializer[X]
[error]  and value tm in object TestTest of type => Materializer[T]
[error]  match expected type Materializer[X]
[error] one error found
[error] (root/compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

Let's look at the code (the SBT project can be found here, https://github.com/q42jaap/scala-macro-inferImplicitValue )

```
// models play json lib's Writes
trait Materializer[-T]

// models play json lib's OWrites
trait OMaterializer[T] extends Materializer[T]

trait T
case class X() extends T

object TestTest {
  // The OMaterializer trait here is the second part of the problem
  implicit val xm = new OMaterializer[X] {}
  // the explicit `tm: Materializer[T]` type declaration here is first part of the problem
  implicit val tm: Materializer[T] = Macro.genMaterializer[T, X]
}

object Macro {
  def genMaterializer[T, M]: Materializer[T] = macro MacroImpl.genMaterializer[T, M]
}

object MacroImpl {
  def genMaterializer[T: c.WeakTypeTag, M: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Materializer[T]] = {
    val tMaterializerTpe = c.universe.appliedType(c.typeOf[Materializer[_]], c.weakTypeOf[M])
    c.inferImplicitValue(tMaterializerTpe)
    c.universe.reify {
      new Materializer[T] {}
    }
  }
}
```

Note the explicit type declaration for `tm`, removing it, fixes the issue. When `xm` is `Materializer[X]` instead of `OMaterializer[X]`, it also works.

`inferImplicitValue` considers both `tm` and `xm` when looking for a `Materializer[X]`. When `xm` is of the type `Materializer[X]` and `tm` has the type
`Materializer[T]` the inferer prefers `xm` over `tm`, because it's an exact match. But when `xm` is `OMaterializer[X]` the compiler cannot decide anymore which one
is better and throws an error.

As I said removing the explicit type declaration from `tm` fixes the problem, because at the time when the macro is executed only `xm`'s type is known.

Can I solve this problem `inferImplicitValue` has? The `silent` option is already true (by default).

In my real use case, I have multiple implementations of `T` (`X`, `Y`, `Z`) and pass then with a union type (like reactivemongo does) to the Macro:

```
genMaterializer[T, Union[X \/ Y \/ Z]]
```

So I have to use the inferImplicitValue to find a Materializer for X, Y and Z.

Note that I have further simplified this case to

```
object ThisDoesntWorkToo {
  implicit val xm = new OMaterializer[X] {}

  implicit val tm: Materializer[T] = withoutMacro[X]

  def withoutMacro[A](implicit m: Materializer[A]): Materializer[A] = m
}
```

which doesn't use macros, but has the same compiler error:

```
[error] TestTest.scala:15: ambiguous implicit values:
[error]  both value xm in object ThisWorks of type => OMaterializer[X]
[error]  and value tm in object ThisWorks of type => Materializer[T]
[error]  match expected type Materializer[X]
[error]   implicit val tm: Materializer[T] = withoutMacro[X]
```

This simplifies the case here, but still leaves me with the problem that a implementation of an implicit val can refer to itself.
The easy and obvious in the latter case is to explicitly provide the implicit value, but as argumented in the final version of the macro I need to use inferImplicitValue
because I have a list of types for which I have to find a Materializer.

Comment: I don't know a solution but to have two implicit values, one for a type and another for its supertype, seems to break implicit resolution rules. And it makes sense to me that it doesn't work. Define implicits only for concrete subtypes of T, not for T alone. That should work.

Comment: The example comes from Json Format[T], where I want an API call to return a homogenous object. I want to automatically add a "_type" property to the JsObject which the writer Json.format[X] generates. For reads-ing the value I need to check _type in the json an choose the correct Reads[X]. This will result in a Format[T] which I think is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "fixes" or "it works", but this is just overload resolution at work.

When both are `Materializer`, `tm` wins because `Mat[T] <:< Mat[X]`.

If the use case is to introduce the implicit `tm` as you show, in that scope, but pick up `xm` implicitly, then this is the only trick I could come up with:

```
  implicit val tm: Materializer[T] = {
    val tm = 0
    Macro.genMaterializer[T, X]
  }
```

which works by simply eliminating the implicit `tm` from the explicit scope.

Maybe an ugly macro could generate that block automatically, from which the real macro is expanded. That breaks locality.

Usually, you eliminate an implicit by making it ambiguous, but you want the implicit in this scope. So shadowing removes it from the nested scope only.

This doesn't help, but is natural:

```
object X {
  implicit val xm: OMaterializer[X] = new OMaterializer[X] {}
}
```